# The "Highgui.imread" command does not work OpenCV Android

Tags: android, opencv

When I call **Highgui.imread** command, I get *Unexpected Exception* on my mobile phone.

I want to load an Image from SDCard to a MAT variable.

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/image1.jpg");
if(imgFile.exists())
{ 
 Mat pic1 = Highgui.imread(imgFile.getAbsolutePath()); 
}
```

I am using **Galaxy Tab 10.1** + **Android OS: 3.2** kernel ver: 2.6.36.3

**The Error on Device:**
"*The application project1 (process prj.project) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.*"

Thank you for your help in advance.

Regards,
Ali

**LogCat:**

```
02-06 11:08:23.620: W/dalvikvm(5853): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/opencv/highgui/Highgui;    
02-06 11:08:23.620: D/AndroidRuntime(5853): Shutting down VM    
02-06 11:08:23.620: W/dalvikvm(5853): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400fc760)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853): FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at photo.klu.PhotoKLUActivity$1.onClick(PhotoKLUActivity.java:89)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3127)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:12025)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java: findLibrary returned null    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:425)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.<clinit>(Highgui.java:313)    
02-06 11:08:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(5853):     ... 12 more    
02-06 11:08:25.640: I/dalvikvm(5853): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3    
02-06 11:08:25.640: I/dalvikvm(5853): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Check the logs for the actuall exception and stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The openCV library is not attached to your application.
Please do the following (i assume that the openCV library is imported to your workspace).
On Package Explorer > Right click on the application project > properties > under Library click Add > select openCV
Be sure that on Java Build Path you don't have anything related to openCV

Answer (score 1):

If you couldn't configurate opencv check this tutorial
http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

If you call a method from openCv sdk for android firstly you've to implement;

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mOpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
@Override
public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
   switch (status) {
       case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
       {
      Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
      // Create and set View
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
       } break;
       default:
       {
      super.onManagerConnected(status);
       } break;
   }
    }
};
```

and then call below in your method.

```
 if (!OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_2, this, mOpenCVCallBack))
    {
      Log.e(TAG, "Cannot connect to OpenCV Manager");
    }
```